# How do I kill three juggernauts in Spec Ops: Survival mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have been playing the Spec Ops Survival mode map "Resistance" for a while now, and I keep dying when all the juggernauts start coming!  what is the best gun to deal with them quickly?  Some people say using C4 is the best way, is this true?

Comment: Lots of answers to this question!

Answer (score 11):

Grenade launchers ('noob toobs'), sniper rifles, C4, and other explosives are all pretty useful, but what you need the most is time.

If you can find a place where you can see them at a range, or you can glitch them into staying away from you, you'll survive a lot longer.  I've killed quite a few juggernauts in co-op with a friend, and usually I'd be the 'bait' while he laid down somewhere out of the way with a sniper rifle and laid into them.  When I could I'd find a place to hide and shoot them with explosive weapons, or, in a pinch, an LMG.

There are some areas where you can let your friend 'die' and they will keep the juggernauts busy while you kill them.  The most popular is to block a doorway with your co-op buddy's downed body.  You have to revive the buddy every so often so that you don't lose the match, however.

In Modern Warfare 2, I also found that juggernauts would freeze if they were unable to path to me - hiding under a table helped, for instance.  They'd just stand there, unable to determine how to get to me, and I'd snipe them in the head over and over again.

If co-op "cheesing" them isn't an option, and/or you've got cash to burn, there are a few weapons and special items that can help:

- Sentry guns can do good damage to Juggernauts, although they will destroy them quickly if left undefended.  They also take a good long time to get spun up, and won't even try to lock onto a target if you're standing in an area anywhere between the gun and the target.  On a Juggernaut round, I'll tend to move my gun to a position where it has a long line of sight on the enemy, and I'm standing closer to him than the gun is.
- Predator missiles and air strikes can quickly kill a single Juggernaut, or perhaps a couple if they're bunched together.
- Riot shield teams are moderately effective against Juggernauts.  You may lose a couple, but if all four are focusing fire, they can take down one on their own most of the time.  If you're supporting them, (or a sentry is) you can often get away with fewer losses.
- Items that increase your survivability (auto revive/body armor) are obviously helpful.

Flash grenades are the surprise winners here - they can stun a Juggernaut (and in the riot shielder's case, cause him to drop his defenses) so that you can go for headshots without taking damage.  Also, since the Juggernaut(s) aren't firing, the effectiveness of your other items is also increased.  The only downside is that their head tends to move while they're stunned, making headshots harder.

Comment: Co-Op "Cheesing" is always the best option. The advantages of double-teaming and concentrated fire always outweighs the danger of a teammate going down.

Comment: ageny86 covered most of it, so I won't bother a second answer, but I'll point out that he somewhat undersells the C4 and LMG.  When a jugg round starts you can normally huck about 3 C4s near the nearest smoke marker to you where one is repelling in.  You have to time it right, but done effectively you can kill or maim one right off the bat.  Secondly, there is no speed penalty for LMGs in Spec Ops, so having one of these bad boys is really worth it once you can afford it.  Aim for the head as well, it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Sniper rifle against Juggernauts, Are you serious?

Comment: @RakeshJuyal amazingly, it only takes 1 clip of a RSASS to kill one

Answer (score 6):

While costly, the most effective method I've been using are predator missiles.

Answer (score 4):

The nice thing about Juggernauts are that they are dumb.

If I'm on my own, I shoot and scoot. I move around and as they follow me they wander into pre-positioned claymores, dynamically positioned C4 and just good old rifle fire. 
Once they are nice and bunched up I drop a Predator on them (or if I'm feeling particularly flush, an Air Strike. Expensive, but satisfying).

In co-op, we practice fire and manouver. One person rails into them while the other runs away. Again, after a minute or two of this, one of us drops a predator on them as by then they are normally bunched up.

The fundamental part of both of these is to move in a fashion that you can predict their next path. Don't run away too far or they might split and travel towards you from different angles - a DISASTER.

These tactics also work well with the Juggernaut / Troops combo. Be sure to *keep* moving and focus on killing the troops - just ignore the juggernauts until the environment is clear. I also try and keep the Juggernauts away from my turrets - they don't seem to do that much damage and they are expensive to replace.

Finally - keep a cool head. Be patient with them and don't panic! :)

Answer (score 2):

1 flash grenade, 1 striker clip, 1 dead juggernaut. Way cheaper than predator, just don't let them get together

Comment: Well, sucks for you: The problem is, when there are three, two of them are always in tight proximity of each other, if not all three together.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I have found that taking your time and letting them follow you, with 1 teammate head-shotting with a sniper too, is the best way to do things.

Answer (score 2):

As a solo player, in my view a combination of claymores, which are after all cheaper than C4, and leading them around until they are all moving together works best.  Depending on how close they are to each other, you may even kill all three before you run out of claymores.  Place them just around a corner; don't leave them in plain sight, or the Juggernauts will shoot them.

Use cars with the claymores if there are any on the map - set the claymore so it will blow up the car when tripped.  For example, on Resistance, lead them into the centre street, plant a claymore in the road behind the bumper of a car at 45 degrees (i.e. facing the corner formed between the bumper and the sidewalk), then duck into the apartment.  Juggernaut walks down pavement, detonates claymore, claymore detonates car.  Only doable once, of course.

Once you're out of claymores, find the longest sightline you can, lure them to one end, sprint to the other, lie down and put lead downrange.  Alternatively, you may find a Striker will finish all three up close in a single load if none have actually died from the claymore assault course.

Answer (score 2):

Just drop 5-6 C4's right under the chopper and when he hits the ground, blow them. Instant kill. Just make sure he is on the ground first, or else it is a waste.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to kill juggs is with the MP7. One clip to the face and regular/riotshield juggs die, two maybe three clips for those huge juggs that come in the later rounds. If you don't hit them in the head with the whole clip it usually weakens them enough that a knife or two will finish them.

Answer (score 1):

I put two claymores on the side of the door for both doors. Maximum 7 on any map. That takes out two, and a predator missile takes out the last.

Or, just go up to it flash and shoot and done - three juggs dead.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, in resistance, if you are at the center street, you will find that the juggernaut will drop down right next to a car (the blue one). Once he drops and looks for you, stand on the opposite side of the car and shoot his head. Once you shoot him continuously through the top of the car, he will drop dead! (Through the whole thing he will most likely not shoot you as much as running right at him/her!

Answer (score 1):

In Resistance no ammo is needed. Just go in the restaurant and box area, lead him to it, and melee him. Run to the other side and he'll shoot, however he will miss often. Be quick.

Comment: You say "no ammo is needed" but you say "shoot". Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

So far the best special op soloplay on mw3 is bakara- the insane level one, why? because you have a hiding spot, there are two bldgs that you can hide in their second floor, one is close to where you can get explosives, the other is close to air support. very rarely will an enemy climb the second floor but it's far better than having enemies coming from all directions. As it turns out, juggernauts are not that difficult to kill-- you need machine guns and I mean two of them! buy the sleight hand for fast reloading- normally ppl get killed while reloading, this one does it fast. fire up a flash bang then blast that son of a bitch in the head. now when you have multiples with air support at the same time, what I do is I buy the riot shield squad a level in advance (ie if they are coming on level 11 I buy riot shield squad before level 10) then as soon as I send them down, I also buy a predator drone... I go upstairs to my safe-location, riotshield guys kill the other regular enemies and I send a predator missile to one of the juggernauts as soon as he gets off the chopper, one less juggernaut to kill makes a happy game.

Answer (score 0):

I normally get squads and predators for them.

Answer (score -2):

A headshot with the Rocket launcher should kill a juggernaut with a single shot.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! Please refrain from saying what was already said.

Answer (score -4):

One MSR 360 sniper shot kills 2 juggernauts.